# SugarCRM popup window snapshotForm

Tags: javascript, sugarcrm

My company has a customer who needs some somewhat complex asset system of self referencing elements. Think of it like a building that has the walls, made of bricks, it has a heating system with a boiler and pipes and radiators and each of these are divided into components too. Each such component, the building, the wall and it's bricks, are stored separately as instances of the asset module.

When filling out the relationship between these assets, you can use the usual pop-up selector window doodad thing, but as soon as we try searching for anything, the system suddenly starts screaming about navigating away from the page.

Now I've traced down exactly what's going on here, there's a JS function defined in src_files\include\javascript\sugar_3.js called snapshotForm that records what the popup form contains on load and then it compares this recorded value with it's state on-close or navigate away to see if it's ok to just move on or if it should throw a tantrum.

Now I can't see anywhere in the module, either sugar/custom/module/udef_asset or sugar/module/udef_asset where anything would get in the way of this snapshot, so my question is simple:

Where can I update the snapshot in a way that ensures the whole page has loaded first? Does anyone have any alternative ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution to my problem, it was due to a dependant dropdown in the child Create form.

The dropdown had a blank default value and thus was being snapshotted with that blank value. However, once the Sugar systems got a second glance, they realised "hey, you can't be blank, that's not allowed value considering your dependencies!" and thus changed it.

Therefore, on searching for another record, it threw the confirmation.

**To find the error** I ran the following in the Chrome js console:

```
snapshotForm(document.getElementById("form_QuickCreate_udef_asset"))
```

which showed me what the current snapshot would be and:

```
editViewSnapshots[document.getElementById("form_QuickCreate_udef_asset").id]
```

which showed me the original snapshot taken. I spotted the error as being in the somewhat complex string `...s_1_nameasset_statusDraftasset_imagedescriptio...` where we find the asset_status = Draft bit. In the original, it didn't have the Draft there.

**To fix**, I could have added blank as an option to the default dependant options, but instead I set the value as default away from blank so that it would load in with the appropriate value.